# Handle change event of all input fields without using refs

Tags: reactjs

I have read that using refs at all is anti-pattern in react. So I am using the function below to get the values of inputs.
I have three input fields in  my child component : name, username and password.

To get their value I do :

```
 handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        inputVal: e.target.value
      })
    }
```

But I don't want to write the same function thrice for all three fields, so how can I do this for the specific input field changed in one function handleChange?

Answer (score 1):

You can abstract the `input` elements into their own component and declare a `handleChange` function within that component that accepts a passed `setState` function.

```
function Input({ name, value, setState }) {
  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

You can then declare your individual states in the parent component and pass both the `state` and `setState` to the child components to render/handle.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="App"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
const { useState } = React;

function Input({ name, value, setState }) {

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <input type="text" name={name} value={value} onChange={handleChange} placeholder={name}/>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(null);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div class="container">
    <form action="">
      <Input name="first-name" value={firstName} setState={setFirstName} />
      <Input name="last-name" value={lastName} setState={setLastName} />
    </form>
    <p>First Name: {firstName}</p>
    <p>Last Name: {lastName}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('App'));

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pull the state up to the parent component where these input fields will be called and pass the handleChange function to each of the input element as a prop.

```
<input type=“text” ... onChange={handleChange} />
```

Add all your logic for how the values should be saved in the state using your `handleChange` function.

This way, regardless of which element change you want handled, all you have to do is pass the handleChange function as a prop and set the value in the state as (say) an object with keys as field name which can be retrieved from the `event` argument passed to the `handleChange` function