# React - Should I have a different input change event for each form input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm building a mortgage calculator app and I want to have it update in real-time in front of the user. To do this I need to update state whenever input is changed so that the component rerenders.

I plan to do this using the `onChange` event on each input field, my question is should the `onChange` event call a different function for each input to update that state property, or is there a way to have one function, and change the state property that is being updated.

For example here is my class Component with the form, state, and onInputChange function

```
class Calculator extends Component {
    state = {
        price: 250000,
        term: 20
    };

    onInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ price: event.target.value })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label htmlFor="propertyPrice">Property Price</label>
                    <input 
                        type="number" 
                        id="propertyPrice" 
                        name="propertyPrice"
                        value={this.state.price}
                        onChange={this.onInputChange}
                    />

                    <label htmlFor="term">Mortgage Term</label>
                    <input 
                        type="term" 
                        id="term" 
                        name="term"
                        value="3"
                    />

                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see on the Property Price input I'm using the `onChange` event to call the function `onInputChange`, which directly updates the price in the state. Do I need a new function for the mortgage term input, or can I use the one function and just change which state property I'm updating, if so, how can I determine which state property is being updated in the function?

Comment: Maybe this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63870067/how-can-i-have-only-one-onchange-for-several-inputs

Comment: That is the perfect way to do it.

Comment: This is how I did it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:-

- Create a single `onInputChange()` like this

```
 onInputChange = (name, value) = {
    this.setState({[name]: value})
  }
```

- Now create any number of inputs but make sure your onChange handler receives a function like this

```
onChange = {(e) => onInputChange(nameOfInput, e.target.value)}
```

Comment: I did it a similar way, except I took the the property names from event object. It's cleaner, and I don't have to run the actual function on each rerender. Which is bad practise onInputChange = (event) => {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        this.setState({[name]: value});
    };

Answer (score 0):

Make your form input tags name same as state name and then you can add this for every input's onChange handler.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}
```